# Adding a List to Json ObjectNode

Tags: java, json

```
ObjectNode row = Json.newObject();
row.put("0", a);
row.put("1", x);
row.put("2", y);
```

now I have list

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

How can I add this to the row?

Comment: What are a x and y..Are they int, string etc

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `putArray` method which creates an `ArrayNode`. Then you should fill it with the elements from your list.

```
ArrayNode arrayNode = row.putArray("myList");
for (String item : list) {
    arrayNode.add(item);
}
```

Comment: addAll expects an ArrayNode or a liste of JsonObjects, you'll want to iterate through your list to add its strings to the new ArrayNode.

Comment: @EricMaziade, you are right. I have mistakenly spotted that the `addAll` accepts a [Collection](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)). However, only collection of `JsonNode`s. I'll update my answer - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional way of creating an arrayNode and populate it elements from a stream.  It does the same as above [fracz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878514/fracz) answer :

```
    yourStringList.stream()
        .collect(Collector.of(
            () -> row.putArray("myList"), 
            (arrayNode, item) -> arrayNode.add(item), 
            (arrayNode1, arrayNode2) -> { arrayNode1.addAll(arrayNode2);  return arrayNode1; },
            Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH
        ));
```

Essentially, it defines a custom collector to accumulate the elements provided by the stream.  Some explanations:

- the first argument `() -> row.putArray("myList")` defines the function which will provide the object to accumulate the items (called the *supplier* function).  In our case this function will provide the `ArrayNode` and is the equivalent of `ArrayNode arrayNode = row.putArray("myList");` statement in the above answer.
- the second argument `(arrayNode, item) -> arrayNode.add(item)` defines the *accumulator* function whose role is to add the elements.  In the left side of the `->` operator, the first variable (e.g. `arrayNode`) refers to the container defined in the first argument while the second (e.g. `item`) refers to the element to accumulate provided by the stream. This function does the same job as the statement `arrayNode.add(item);` inside the loop in the above example.
- the third argument `(arrayNode1, arrayNode2) -> { arrayNode1.addAll(arrayNode2);  return arrayNode1; }` is the *combiner* function which is used if the stream is collected in parralel (for instance if we had `.parralelStream()` instead of `.stream()`).  Its role is to merge two  accumulators toghether and this is why the function has two argumets of the same type.  We define this function such that it will add all elements accumulated in the second accumulator into the first accumulator and return this first accumulator.
- the fourth argument `Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH` define one or more optons to the process.  In this case, `IDENTITY_FINISH` simply states that no *finisher* function will be provided (to further process the accumulator object) or, in other words, that the finisher function is the identity function (no treatment done).

This solution might seems more complex at first but it leverages all the power of functionnal programming.  For instance, we could stream objects, extract a String property with the `map` function, `filter` it, etc. before collecting everything:

```
    yourObjectList.stream()
        .map(o -> o.getTheStringProperty())
        .filter(o -> o.length() > MIN_SIZE)
        .collect(Collector.of(
            () -> row.putArray("myList"), 
            (arrayNode, item) -> arrayNode.add(item), 
            (arrayNode1, arrayNode2) -> { arrayNode1.addAll(arrayNode2);  return arrayNode1; },
            Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH
        ));
```